# Create decorative image border with CSS?

Tags: images, css

I'm trying to create a custom border style for several images on a website (building in WordPress.) Is there a way to get the style shown below with pure CSS? (i.e.: trying to add the dark green wavy border shown below)

[image]

Comment: *building in WordPress* does not mean this is WorsPress specific. This is generic CSS which should be asked on [so]

Comment: sorry my mistake- new to using stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links can help you get started:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759102/wave-border-in-css

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895895/creating-a-droplet-like-border-effect-in-css/25903879#25903879

You can do an effect like this using pseudo-elements and css3.

You could even turn the border into an [SVG](http://atelierbram.github.io/frame-patterns/):

```
.divider {
  border: 32px solid transparent;
  border-image:url(../svg/wave_96x96_border-image.svg) 32 round round;
  background-color: #3c93c9;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi @grlwondr if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.